# Too many warning and info messages during hive startup

Tags: warnings, hive, startup

Currently, I use `hadoop-2.2.0.tar.gz` and `hive-0.11.0.tar.gz` to study hadoop and hive. I just extract files from these two tarballs and set the environment for them.

Then I startup the hive with the `hive`command. I find it too many `WARN` and `INFO` messages as the following. Is there any way to eliminate these messages? I haven't set any configuration yet. Whether the version of hadoop is not compatible with the hive?

```
14/03/21 09:24:52 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir.recursive is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive
14/03/21 09:24:52 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.max.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize
14/03/21 09:24:52 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.min.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize
14/03/21 09:24:52 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.min.split.size.per.rack is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.rack
14/03/21 09:24:52 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.min.split.size.per.node is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.node
14/03/21 09:24:52 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
14/03/21 09:24:52 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
14/03/21 09:24:52 WARN conf.Configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.LoopingByteArrayInputStream@6295eb:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
14/03/21 09:24:52 WARN conf.Configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.LoopingByteArrayInputStream@6295eb:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/ljq/hive-0.11.0/lib/hive-common-0.11.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/ljq/hive_job_log_ljq_8719@rhel6-hadoop1_201403210924_1350715255.txt
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ljq/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ljq/hive-0.11.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
hive (default)>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the next link: [org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.java](http://people.apache.org/~hashutosh/hive-clover/common/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.html?line=215#src-215%20org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.java) these values are defined inside the class, and these are deprecated just now, so this warnings always will be showed. The solution proposed in this another link: [hadoop.apache.org/Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) is just omit warnings. You must edit the file $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/log4j.properties and uncomment the line after the legend:

> # Uncomment the following line to turn off configuration deprecation warnings.
>
> log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation=WARN

Comment: I uncomment that line. But the deprecate info still there while I start hive again.